# Can I share an private AMI with another management console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I have an AMI I made on an account I use for teaching. I would like to copy and use that AMI on my private account. I figured it would just be as easy as downloading from one account and uploading to the other but I can't find a download option (supposedly there are some things available in s3). I tried to edit the permissions and add the account id for the root user of my private account and that didn't work either.

Is it possible to share a private AMI with another user on another management console?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the modify-image-attribute console command to change the launch permission to add another user ID

Comment: This will work even if the if is in another console entirely? Can you give an example of the command?

Comment: example taken from AWS documentation: 
aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-12345678 --launch-permission "{\"Add\":[{\"UserId\":\"123456789012\"}]}"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/sharingamis-explicit.html

Comment: I tried that command with the user ID being the 12 digit AWS ID without the hyphens. When I sign into the other console I still don't see the AMI.

Comment: Also there is a web interface for adding a user by their AWS ID but that doesn't work either.